# Wordpress Plugin Generating PDF and Xls Documents

Tags: wordpress, tcpdf, phpexcel

I'm writing a web application for a client that needs to be packaged in a wordpress plugin. The application is built on top of a soap api that returns an array of results that I need to output to a pdf and/or excel document. I'm using two third party libraries to generate the pdf and excel files (tcpdf and phpexcel), but Wordpress won't allow them to modify the header from inside of the plugin to return different types of content. Does anyone know how I can generate and return a pdf/excel document from inside of a Wordpress plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following TCPDF exmaple link...this will show you how to create pdf using TCPDF.

```
http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php
```

You can also refer post2pdf-converter wordpress plugin which will show you how to convert posts to pdf. 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post2pdf-converter/